# Modelling custom form using django crispy form

Tags: html, django, django-crispy-forms

I have this problem where I want to model the style of a field using django-crispy-forms from a template downloaded from the internet.

The field looks like this:

[image]

and the html for this section is (using bootstrap5 obviously):

```
<div class="form-group mb-4">
    <label for="id_username">Username</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
            <svg class="icon icon-xs text-gray-600" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 
                20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <g 
                transform="translate(0.000000,20.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" 
                fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none"> <path d="M72 168 c-18 -18 -14 -56 
                7 -68 26 -14 50 -3 57 26 11 42 -34 72 -64 42z M48 59 c-34 -20 -17 
                -29 52 -29 39 0 70 4 70 10 0 26 -87 40 -122 19z"/></svg>
        </span>                 

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="admin" name="username" 
            id="id_username" autofocus required>

    </div>  
</div>
```

Using django-crispy-forms I try to model this with `Layout()` from `crispy_forms.layout` and using a form class in `forms.py` in django:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, MultiField, Fieldset, Submit, Div, HTML, Field, Row

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(
                    HTML('<span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">'
                         '<svg class="icon icon-xs text-gray-600" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
                             '<g transform="translate(0.000000,20.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none">' 
                             '<path d="M72 168 c-18 -18 -14 -56 7 -68 26 -14 50 -3 57 26 11 42 -34 72 -64 42z M48 59 c-34 -20 -17 -29 52 -29 39 0 70 4 70 10 0 26 -87 40 -122 19z"/>'
                        '</svg>'
                        '</span>'
                    ),
                    Field('username',   css_class='form-control', placeholder='admin', autofocus=True, required=True),
                    css_class="input-group"
                ),
                css_class="form-group mb-4"
            ),
        )

    username = forms.CharField(label=_('Username'),)
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Upon inspecting the html from browser:

```
<div class="form-group mb-4">
    <div class="input-group"> 
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
            <!-- THAT SVG CODE -->
        </span> 
        <div id="div_id_username" class="control-group"> 
             <label for="id_username" class="control-label requiredField">
                    Username
                    <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
             </label> 
        ####==>#### <div class="controls">
             <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" class="form-control textinput textInput" placeholder="admin" autofocus="True" required="" id="id_username"> </div> </div> 
        ####==>#### </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pretty close here but here is the problem, using `Field` from `crispy_forms.layout` adds a `<div>` on the `<input>` text field...

Any idea I could get rid of that?

Obviously I could copy and paste the whole code using `HTML()` from `crispy_forms.layout` in `Layout()` but then it defeat the purpose of using django forms... - I could have just render it from templates and extract the field from `request.POST`.

Any idea how to solve this?
Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get round it by creating a `template` called `input_field_only.html`.

```
{% load crispy_forms_field %}

<input type="{{ field.widget_type }}" class="form-control" placeholder="admin" name="{{ field.name }}" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
```

Save into `templates` directory.

Then in `forms.py` I will use the new custom template together with the `LoginForm`

```
class InputFieldOnly(Field):
    template = '<APP_NAME>/templates/input_field_only.html'


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div(
                    HTML('<span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">'
                         '<svg class="icon icon-xs text-gray-600" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
                             '<g transform="translate(0.000000,20.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none">' 
                             '<path d="M72 168 c-18 -18 -14 -56 7 -68 26 -14 50 -3 57 26 11 42 -34 72 -64 42z M48 59 c-34 -20 -17 -29 52 -29 39 0 70 4 70 10 0 26 -87 40 -122 19z"/>'
                        '</svg>'
                        '</span>'
                    ),
                                        # Add InputFieldOnly
                    InputFieldOnly('username'),
                    css_class="input-group"
                ),
                css_class="form-group mb-4"
            ),
        )
    # Add the widget argument here
    username = forms.CharField(label=_('Username'),)
```

Hope it help for some who encountered the same problem!

Comment: One thing is that I seems cannot get widget attribute to work using this method, for example `placeholder`, `required` don't work and I don't want to hard code into the template. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As part of crispy there is [`PrependedAppendedText`](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/main/crispy_forms/bootstrap.py) model which is part of the crispy.bootstrap module that replaces the `Field` model.

https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/crispy-bootstrap5/blob/main/crispy_bootstrap5/templates/bootstrap5/layout/prepended_appended_text.html

This way you don't have to build your own widget and lose all the functionality of crispy's errors etc etc